# 2 dimensional JSON parse

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object as such

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Iden": "12",
            "Date": "01/23/2011",
            "City": "Clearwater",
            "State": "FL"
        },
        {
            "Iden": "12",
            "Date": "02/09/2012",
            "City": "Elgin",
            "State": "IL"
        },
        {
            "Iden": "00010-LV01-12",
            "Date": "06/22/2010",
            "City": "Newport Beach",
            "State": "CA"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, it has 3 rows and 4 columns. How do I use the .each in jquery to iterate through this object?

I tried:

```
$.each(Data, function () {
```

but it only did the first iteration

Comment: use Data.d as parameter for the .each

Comment: If you assigned the whole parsed object to `Data`, you probably want `Data.Data`. Btw, http://jsonlint.org/ is great for formatting JSON **and** it validates your JSON :)

Comment: show code where you are accessing the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.each()` can iterate over arrays, maps/objects, but the function parameters have slightly different meanings in each case:

```
$.each(Data.Data, function(i) {
    // 'this' is the array element, i is the index
    $.each(this, function(key, value) {
        // 'this' is the value of the object item
        // key is the map/object key, value is value
    });
});
```

It is important to note that `this` is always in Object format, even if it is a string or number.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/acySP/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a nested loop. Like so:

```
jQuery.each( Data, function( ) {
    // `this` now points to the row of data
    jQuery.each( this, function( key, value ) {
        // process here
    } );
} );
```

EDIT: Changed inner callback to use `key, value` as arguments - more applicable for this scenario.

Comment: Why do this?  He only has one array.

Comment: @Chris: `$.each()` can iterate over maps/objects as well.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I also didn't notice that @Nate referred to the properties as "columns" so this solution makes more sense in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

if this is in an ajax request such as

```
  $.getJSON( url, function ( data){
     /* main JSON object is data,   array Data is inside main object, need to iterate over it*/
      $.each( data.Data, function(key, item){
       $('body').append( '<p>'+item.City +', '+item.State+'</p>');
     })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to using `$.map` to get Data

see demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PQcFx/5/